# kernel display DRM CRTC scan out process

Tags: kernel, x11

I search google
https://man.archlinux.org/man/drm-kms.7.en

```
CRTCs
A CRTC short for CRT Controller is an abstraction representing a part of the chip that contains a pointer to a scanout buffer.
```

and

```
Planes
A plane respresents an image source that can be blended with or overlayed on top of a CRTC during the scanout process
```

Question

1. What is full name CRTC?
2. What is "scanout buffer" and "scanout process"

Comment: Relevant: https://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/HowVideoCardsWork/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your questions.

1. It is nothing but a display controller IP or sometimes it is called display engine, for historical reason it is called CRTC as in the earlier days cathode ray display monitors were used. A CRTC short for CRT Controller is an abstraction representing a part of the chip that contains a pointer to a scan-out buffer. Therefore, the number of CRTCs available determines how many independent scan-out buffers can be active at any given time.
2. scan-out process is an instance of program to render the image on display, and the frame you want to display is called scan-out buffer.